# C# Form Controls Won't Update with Multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, user-interface

I've been playing around with multithreading and reading up on some of the questions here, but I haven't found an answer that directly addresses my concerns here.

I have an application that runs on a single thread, except for a progress bar in a separate window. Based on my research, I need to create a new thread for that form which will redraw the form's controls as it's properties change. I've reduced the problem to a simple example below:

Here's the 'main' program:

```
class Program
{
    static MyForm form;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        form = new MyForm();
        form.Show();

        doWork();

        form.Close();
    }

    //arbitrary example of processing that takes some period of time
    static void doWork()
    {
        while (form.Value < 100000) 
        {
            form.ChangeVal();
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

...And here's the Form. I'm not including the auto-generated stuff from VS.

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    private int val;
    public int Value
    {
        get { return val; }
        set { val = value; }
    }

    public Thread GUIupdater;


    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Refresh();
    }

    private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GUIupdater = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GUIupdaterThread));
        GUIupdater.Start();

        this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(killThreadOnClose);
    }

    public void ChangeVal()
    {
        val++;
    }

    private void changeLabel(string s)
    {
        label.Text = s;
        label.Refresh();
    }
    private delegate void labelChanger(string s);
    private void GUIupdaterThread()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Invoke(new labelChanger(changeLabel), new object[]{val.ToString()} );
            Thread.Sleep(100); //100 ms
        }
    }
    private void killThreadOnClose(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        GUIupdater.Abort();
    }
}
```

So, my intention here is to have the calculations running constantly, with the window's graphics updating reasonably quickly. When I run the program, however, the invoke function is only called once, and the label never actually updates!

Any and all feedback is appreciated. If you want to view the code in an IDE you can download my project from [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ipekg72wwhya25l/AADyXSEFrk3z3XRY-70nghfla?dl=0)

Edits:

- When I add Console.WriteLine Statements, I discovered that the GUIupdaterThread (the thing that's meant to update the GUI) loop always 'breaks' on the Invoke statement, never reaching 'Thread.Sleep'. I changed it to 'BeginInvoke', which causes the loop to function properly, but this hasn't changed the fact that the GUI doesn't update.

CLARIFICATIONS:

About my 'actual' project:

- The main thread here in 'Program' simulates my software, which is a plugin implementing an interface. My decision to alter val / value in that thread, not in the thread created by the window, was deliberate.
- I'm constrained to using .NET 4.0 . any more recent features can't help me

Comment: It seems like you're doing it backwards.  Your calculations should be running on the threads not the updating of the form.

Comment: Because of the system I'm working with, the calculations MUST absolutely run on the main thread, and it's my goal to display the results in the GUI window. There has to be some way to get this done, right?

Comment: I would get rid of all those while-loops and just use a timer.  I see nothing in your code that requires a separate thread.  If this is just an exercise, then follow a BackgroundWorker tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest overriding the form's `OnPaint` method.  Then inside `ChangeVal`, after you have updated whatever variables/data you need to update, call `this.Invalidate` which should trigger the form to repaint itself.

Or if you're just updating a single label, call label.Refresh in your `ChangeVal` method.  The form should update correctly.  Here's an example that worked for me:

This form has a single label on it.

```
public partial class ProgressForm : Form
{

    private int currentValue = 0;

    public ProgressForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void ChangeValue(int newValue)
    {
        currentValue = newValue;
        lblValue.Text = string.Format("Current value: {0}", currentValue);
        lblValue.Refresh();   //Call Refresh to make the label update itself
    }
}

static class Program
{
    private static ProgressForm progressForm = null;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        //Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        //Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        //Application.Run(new Form1());

        progressForm = new ProgressForm();
        progressForm.Show();

        doWork();

        progressForm.Close();
    }


    //arbitrary example of processing that takes some period of time
    static void doWork()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 100000)
        {
            progressForm.ChangeValue(i);
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            i++;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code worked excellently for me! It seems, based on the answers given, that for my particular situation (where calculations are in a parent window), single threading is the best choice.

Answer (score 3):

Since in your application you have GUI thread (main thread) - all UI controls will be accessible from this thread only.

There are several approaches how to update controls from other threads.
I would like to recommend you to use one of modern and native approaches based on [Progress < T > class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx) (it's native for .Net platform).

Comment: You're saying that my main thread is my GUI thread? What about the one that I created within my form?

Comment: Also, I'm stuck using .Net 4.0. It looks like this is 4.5+ only. I'll be sure to add that to my question

Comment: @BrentAllard 4.0 is unsupported for quite some time now. You probably already run 4.5.2 on your machine without realizing it and so do your customers. In any case, you *can* add `async/await` and Progress to .NET 4.0 with the BCL.Async package. It's just that there is no reason anymore, since .NET 4 isn't supported

Comment: @BrentAllard also note that TLS 1.2 was added in .NET 4.5.2. You'll have to upgrade at some point, or lose the ability to use HTTPS. Everyone requires at least TLS1.1 and many services require TLS1.2

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following instead as you are trying to access UI control other than main thread (from which it is created).

```
while ( true )
{
    Invoke ( ( Action ) (() =>
    {
       label.Text = val.ToString();
       label.Refresh()
       Application.DoEvents();
    }));

    Thread.Sleep( 100 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I implemented this, and ended up getting the same result, where the GUI label doesn't update. It remains blank.

Comment: I have edited the answer, had forgotten Application.DoEvents(); This will force update.

Comment: I added that to my code, but I'm still not getting any results from the GUI. Check out the edit that I made at the bottom of my question -- Invoke seems to be breaking the execution of the while loop, while never actually making the action happen. Could you try running the code (you can download the project from the link in my question)? This is my first time multi threading with GUI elements, so I might have made some simple mistakes.

Comment: Using `Application.DoEvents` is a bad idea.  There are many articles online that discuss this.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use "backgroundworker".

First add `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;` to initialization part otherwise `InvalidOperationException` occurs.

```
private void btnDoIt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Foo();
}

int total = 0;
private void Foo()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100000; i++)
    {
        total += i;
        this.Text = i.ToString();
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Run next process
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response! Due to design constraints outside of my control, I have to alter the value (in your code, 'total') from my 'Main' Thread, the one in class Program. In my actual project, I'm writing a plugin that implements an interface, so all information has to go through the main thread. Would you advise a different approach?

Comment: This is a bad idea.  `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` merely hides potential problems.  When updating the UI from another thread, the call must be marshaled to the UI thread.  With the `BackgroundWorker` this is done by handling the `ProgressChanged` event and in the DoWork method, calling `ReportProgress`.

Comment: There's no reason to use BackgroundWorker, the same functionality (and more) is offered by Task and Progress<T>. Never mind the very, very bad idea of disabling the cross-thread call check which can result in a garbled UI