# How to download images Asynchronously

Tags: c#

I'm using this method to download an array of images synchronously from the server

```
Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
{
    Bitmap imageBitmap = null;
    try
    {
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
            if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
            {
                imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //Silence is gold.
    }
    displayPic();
    return imageBitmap;
}
```

But I want now to use this method Asynchronously. I changed it to look like this

```
async Task<Bitmap> GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
{
    Bitmap imageBitmap = null;
    try
    {
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            var imageBytes = await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
            if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
            {
                //imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(imageBytes), 0, imageBytes.Length);
                imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(imageBytes), 0, imageBytes.Length);
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //Silence is gold.
    }
    displayPic();
    return imageBitmap;
}
```

But the conversion from string to byte array didn't work and I'm recieving a `null` object from the method every time.

What is the problem that causes making the `imageBitmap` variable become `null` in the second method? How can I solve that?

Comment: Are you sure no Exception was thrown? Maybe remove the try/catch to test this.

Comment: Use `DownloadDataTaskAsync` then you will get byte array and not string

Comment: Yes I'm sure, When I debug threw the method it doesn't enter the try cache part.

Comment: @x...  Worked like a charm :D Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can also use BackGroundWorker tool that provide a callback function check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588884/c-sharp-form-controls-wont-update-with-multithreading/38590510#38590510

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get byte array instead of string. Change this:

```
var imageBytes = await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
```

to this:

```
var imageBytes = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url);
```