# ERROR : Thread was being aborted in c# Windows application

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, progress

I got below error when I used of thread for called waiting form during a long process.

> "An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: **Thread was being aborted**."

Sometimes my code works well but sometimes this error occurred.

```
class ProgressCLS
{
    private static Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(showProgressForm));
    public void startProgress()
    {
        th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(showProgressForm));

        th.Start();
    }

    private static void showProgressForm()
    {              
                Waiting sForm = new Waiting();            
                sForm.ShowDialog();
    }

    public void stopProgress()
    {
            th.Abort();
            th = null;          
    }


}
```

I got this error on `showProgressForm()` Method on `sform.ShowDialog()` Line

and the main program I called this class looks like this:

```
ProgressCLS PC = new ProgressCLS();
PC.startProgress();
TodayDate = txtDate.SelectedDateTime.ToString("yy-MM-dd");
ClearField();
CalculateMSG();
tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
btnShowFolderLocal.Enabled = true;
btnShowFolderTop.Enabled = true;
btnShowDpsFailed.Enabled = true;
btnShowDpsFailed2.Enabled = true;
btnShowFolderTopic.Enabled = true;
ShowMSGButtonClicked = true;
PC.stopProgress();
```

any Idea?

Comment: That's because you used Thread.Abort() and you have a try/catch-em-all statement that you did not post.  Don't catch ThreadAbortException.

Comment: You don't need a separate thread just to display a progress form. Display a *non-modal* form with `Show` instead of `ShowDialog`. If you want to report progress from another task/thread, use `Progress<T>` and subscribe to its event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Form Controls Won't Update with Multithreading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588884/c-sharp-form-controls-wont-update-with-multithreading)

Comment: In fact, don't use `Thread.Abort`. It may not be the big bad ugly wolf it once was but it still a very *bad* code smell, there are **many** ways to handle this type of thing *without* `Thread.Abort`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(showProgressForm));  
public void startProgress()
{
    th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(showProgressForm));
    th.Start();
}
```

Not a big deal, but why do you instantiate your thread twice? Not really clean.
I think only the one in your ctor is mandatory, because you set th = null when calling stopProgress().

Anyway look at your code, and remember that thread are asynchronous, so:

```
        ProgressCLS PC = new ProgressCLS();
        PC.startProgress();
```

It runs your progress form in a dedicated thread (asynchronous, so your code is still running).

```
    TodayDate = txtDate.SelectedDateTime.ToString("yy-MM-dd");
    ClearField();
    CalculateMSG();
    ...
```

You perform a serie of process in the main thread (synchrounously, your progress form still running in the background).

```
        PC.stopProgress();
```

Whatever the status of your progress form, it is aborted. And as you might have missed from the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.abort(v=vs.110).aspx), it "Raises a ThreadAbortException in the thread on which it is invoked". Thus to be fair, it is even Strange that your code "sometimes work", because if it hits the th.Abort() line, it should failed.

A few hints here:

- Usually we run UI form in the main Thread, and process in the Background
- With your current design, you may be in trouble if any of you process (ClearField() and CalculateMSG()) have asynchrounous operation.
- You rarely need to explicitely abort a Thread (only if there is an unexpected error). Just close the form when the progress is done, the Gargbage Collector can do the rest.

Comment: @MajidQafouri why are you using a separate thread? Just call `Show()` instead of `ShowDialog()`

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos when i use show() instead of showDialog() , waiting form not apeared

Comment: @MajidQafouri the form appeared as a top-level form, probably behind your current form. If you want a form to appear as a child of another, you need to supply it as a parameter to [Form.Show](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd(v=vs.110).aspx). The same is true for ShowDialog. Modal vs Non-Modal forms at a basic concept of Windows Forms

Comment: @MajidQafouri [this duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588884/c-sharp-form-controls-wont-update-with-multithreading) shows how to use both a non-modal form and how to update it from a background task

Comment: Yep, Show won't work in a background Thread, as I said normally you run Show in the UI thread, and process in the background.

Comment: @Ouarzy ShowDialog isn't different in that respect. You *can* show a UI from another thread, you can't modify the UI generated by another thread. The difference is that `ShowDialog` behaves as a top-level window

Answer (score 1):

tnx all.
i changed my Progress Class code like this:

```
 //private static Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(showProgressForm));
    private static Thread th;
    public void startProgress()
    {
        th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(showProgressForm));

        th.Start();
    }
```

and it's worked

Comment: As i did before,

Comment: public void stopProgress()
    {
            th.Abort();
            th = null;          
    }